# XSL select and sum a node based on partial match to sibling value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

We have poorly-formed XML coming from an Oracle report.  The report contains thousands of orders.  Each order contains less than a thousand lines.  Each line contains potentially many charges.  We read the XML with an XSL template to clean it up.  I'm having a problem reading the charge section and summarizing each charge type by Order.

Looking at the example below, we have Ack_Line__Hdr_S32 containing the charges.  AckLine_ID2 is the line number.  When the template is called, we have the Order number, but the order number does not contain the line number.  This means, we have the order number '0705181439' and have to evaluate that against the substring first ten characters of line number 0705181439009.

The first XSL solution below worked until the order volume grew.  Now it crashes after some time.  The source XML file is around 50MB.

Here's the detail:

Sample XML:

```
<Charges_and_Fees_S9_Group>
  <Ack_Line___Hdr_S32>
    <AckLine_ID2>0705181439009</AckLine_ID2>
    <On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
      <ChargeItemNumber_ID1>ACCESSCH                 </ChargeItemNumber_ID1>
      <ChargesAndFees_ID3>30.00</ChargesAndFees_ID3>
      <ChargeItemDescription_ID4>Accessorial Charge</ChargeItemDescription_ID4>
    </On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
    <On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
      <ChargeItemNumber_ID1>FLANDED                  </ChargeItemNumber_ID1>
      <ChargesAndFees_ID3>67.12</ChargesAndFees_ID3>
      <ChargeItemDescription_ID4>Freight - Landed Freight</ChargeItemDescription_ID4>
    </On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
    <On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
      <ChargeItemNumber_ID1>FUELSURG                 </ChargeItemNumber_ID1>
      <ChargesAndFees_ID3>27.12</ChargesAndFees_ID3>
      <ChargeItemDescription_ID4>Fuel Surcharge</ChargeItemDescription_ID4>
    </On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
    <AckLine_Freight_ID1>67.12</AckLine_Freight_ID1>
    <AckLine_ChargesAndFees_ID2>57.12</AckLine_ChargesAndFees_ID2>
    <AckLine_FuelSurcharge_ID4>27.12</AckLine_FuelSurcharge_ID4>
    <AckLine_AccessorialSurcharge_ID6>30.00</AckLine_AccessorialSurcharge_ID6>
  </Ack_Line___Hdr_S32>
</Charges_and_Fees_S9_Group>
<Charges_and_Fees_S9_Group>
  <Ack_Line___Hdr_S32>
    <AckLine_ID2>0705181439010</AckLine_ID2>
    <On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
      <ChargeItemNumber_ID1>ACCESSCH                 </ChargeItemNumber_ID1>
      <ChargesAndFees_ID3>30.00</ChargesAndFees_ID3>
      <ChargeItemDescription_ID4>Accessorial Charge</ChargeItemDescription_ID4>
    </On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
    <On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
      <ChargeItemNumber_ID1>FLANDED                  </ChargeItemNumber_ID1>
      <ChargesAndFees_ID3>67.12</ChargesAndFees_ID3>
      <ChargeItemDescription_ID4>Freight - Landed Freight</ChargeItemDescription_ID4>
    </On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
    <On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
      <ChargeItemNumber_ID1>FUELSURG                 </ChargeItemNumber_ID1>
      <ChargesAndFees_ID3>27.12</ChargesAndFees_ID3>
      <ChargeItemDescription_ID4>Fuel Surcharge</ChargeItemDescription_ID4>
    </On_2nd_Item_Number_S19>
    <AckLine_Freight_ID1>67.12</AckLine_Freight_ID1>
    <AckLine_ChargesAndFees_ID2>57.12</AckLine_ChargesAndFees_ID2>
    <AckLine_FuelSurcharge_ID4>27.12</AckLine_FuelSurcharge_ID4>
    <AckLine_AccessorialSurcharge_ID6>30.00</AckLine_AccessorialSurcharge_ID6>
  </Ack_Line___Hdr_S32>
</Charges_and_Fees_S9_Group>
```

Old XSL Template:

```
<xsl:template name="ChargesTotal">
  <xsl:param name="AckLineNumber" />
    <Total_Accessorial>
      <xsl:if test="//AckLine_AccessorialSurcharge_ID6  [substring(../AckLine_ID2, 1, 10)=$AckLineNumber]" >
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(//AckLine_AccessorialSurcharge_ID6  [substring(../AckLine_ID2, 1, 10)=$AckLineNumber]), '#.00')" />
      </xsl:if>
    </Total_Accessorial>  
</xsl:template>
```

New XSL Template:

```
<xsl:template name="ChargesTotal">
  <xsl:param name="AckLineNumber" />
  <xsl:variable name="setSurchargeAcc" select="Ack_Line___Hdr_S32/AckLine_AccessorialSurcharge_ID6[substring(../AckLine_ID2, 1, 10)=$AckLineNumber]"/>
  <Total_Accessorial>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($setSurchargeAcc/AckLine_AccessorialSurcharge_ID6), '#.00')" />
  </Total_Accessorial>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected Output:

```
<Total_Accessorial>60.00</Total_Accessorial>
```

Comment: What does "it crashes" mean exactly, does the application run out of memory? Have you tried to increase the memory for the (Java?) application? Have you tried a different XSLT processor?

Comment: When I say crash, I mean the transformation eventually ends in error on the reporting server after 30 minutes.  I believe the server has 32GB memory dedicated to the XSL processor.  When I attempt to run this locally (using N++ with XML Tools plugin,) this transformation processes the 50MB file in about 10 seconds.  When adding in the template above, I end up killing the program after 30 minutes because I've given up on it.  I haven't tried a different XMLT processor, as these are the two tools I currently have at my disposal.

Comment: So which XSLT processor is used on the server?

Comment: I'm not sure, @MartinHonnen.  The product is Oracle JD Edwards EnterpriseOne Apps 9.1 with Tools 9.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a key

```
<xsl:key name="line-id" match="Charges_and_Fees_S9_Group/Ack_Line___Hdr_S32"
  use="substring(AckLine_ID2, 1, 10)"/>
```

then you can do e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="setSurchargeAcc" select="key('line-id', $AckLineNumber)"/>
```

and

```
<Total_Accessorial>
  <xsl:if test="$setSurchargeAcc">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($setSurchargeAcc/AckLine_AccessorialSurcharge_ID6), '#.00')" />
  </xsl:if>
</Total_Accessorial>
```

Comment: This is great, Martin.  It's solved my issue.  I didn't realize that I could call a key without a corresponding template.  Thank you so much!